# Not allowing forklifts to go through nodes in the network

Tags: anylogic

I have a model with several node locations, and forklifts are used to move some boxes to those nodes. I have no path in the network that goes through any of the nodes, yet the forklifts go through them. As you can see in the attached picture, if a forklift is dropping a box off at the middle node, I want it to follow the red arrow where it goes down the middle path, makes a right turn to the node, then another right turn to the edge of the node, and finally returns from the same path. But what happens now, the forklift follows the grey arrow and goes through the nodes although the paths are not connected through the nodes.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should change your layout such that forklifts move to PointNode elements that reside within a Wall element as below:

[image]

Then, either set navigation type of your transporter fleet to "free space" or use "path-guided" and make sure to draw a path to the central PointNode

PS: I assume you use the Material-handling library with transporters

Answer (score 0):

If you are using transporters you can use "Avoid nodes" and "Avoid paths" feature in TransporterFleet block. You can specify all the rectangular nodes except the target node as nodes to avoid.

See here: [Help - TransporterFleet](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/_Material/reference/TransporterFleet.html?cp=2_1_0_4)